# How to add claim for only one month for users or add a claim for role in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have a problem with claims.

How to add claim for role or user for limited time like I want a user to have access to delete record functionality but only for one month for example, anybody if have idea it will be a huge thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find anything in the official docs about the claim of adding a time limit, but I have an idea. It's a bit more complicated, but should work.

You can create a table specifically to store information about the user and the datetime about the claim. For example:

```
public class ClaimTime
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string CliamType { get; set; }
    public string ClaimValue { get; set; }
    public DateTime ClaimAddedTime { get; set; }
    //Whether to add a time limit
    public bool IsLimited { get; set; }
}
```

When adding a claim for a user, record the current time and save it in the `ClaimTime` table:

```
AppUser user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
Claim claim = new Claim(claimType, claimValue, ClaimValueTypes.String);
IdentityResult result = await userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, claim);

ClaimTime claimTime = new ClaimTime()
{
    UserId = user.Id,
    UserName = user.UserName,
    CliamType = claimType,
    ClaimValue = claimValue,
    ClaimAddedTime = DateTime.Now,
    IsLimited = true
};
_db.ClaimTimes.Add(claimTime);
_db.SaveChanges();
```

When you need to judge whether to delete the user's authorization, you can obtain the current user's information from the database when the user logs in and make a judgment:

```
AppUser user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);

var UserClaimDelete = _db.ClaimTimes.Where(c => c.UserId == user.Id && c.IsLimited == true && c.ClaimValue == "xxx").FirstOrDefault();
var TimeNow = DateTime.Now;
if(TimeNow.Subtract(UserClaimDelete.ClaimAddedTime).TotalDays >= 30)
{
    Claim claim = User.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == "xxx" && x.Value == "xxx").FirstOrDefault();
    await userManager.RemoveClaimAsync(user, claim);
}
```

Maybe someone else has an easier way, but hopefully this will help you.